# Error Parsing JSON with escaped quotes

Tags: javascript, json

I am getting the following json object when I call the URL from Browser which I expect no data in it.

```
"{\"data\":[], \"SkipToken\":\"\", \"top\":\"\"}"
```

However, when I tried to call it in javascript it gives me `error Parsing Json message`

```
dspservice.callService(URL, "GET", "", function (data) {
    var dataList = JSON.parse(data);
)};
```

This code was working before I have no idea why all of a sudden stopped working and throwing me error.

Comment: If he doesn't escape the double quotes then his code won't even _run_.

Comment: @StuartWagner JSON.parse handles escaped quotes just fine

Comment: in browser dev tools network tab inspect the actual response ...can run it through jsonlint.com but I suspect it's not json

Comment: I removed my answer, since it is invalid, however, here is a fiddle of your issue if you would like to expand on what is wrong, since the fiddle is showing your JSON is good: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jasonwilczak/3zqx26h5/1/)

Comment: Could you add a `console.log` in your callback and see what `data` outputs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there is nothing wrong with the JSON string you gave us, the only other explanation is that the `data` being passed to your function is something *other* than what you listed.

To test this hypothesis, run the following code:

```
dspservice.callService(URL, "GET", "", handler(data));

function handler(data) {
    var goodData = "{\"data\":[], \"SkipToken\":\"\", \"top\":\"\"}";
    alert(goodData);                         // display the correct JSON string
    var goodDataList = JSON.parse(goodData); // parse good string (should work)
    alert(data);                             // display string in question
    var dataList = JSON.parse(data);         // try to parse it (should fail)
}
```

If the `goodData` JSON string can be parsed with no issues, and `data` appears to be incorrectly-formatted, then you have the answer to your question.

Place a breakpoint on the first line of the `handler` function, where `goodData` is defined.  Then step through the code.  From what you told me in your comments, it is still crashing during a JSON parse, but I'm willing to wager that it is failing on the *second* parse and not the first.

Comment: Then how were you getting the JSON parsing error in the first place?

Comment: You should at least be able to get to the `JSON.parse()` call in the third line of my sample code.  Are you using Chrome or Firefox?

Comment: @ilyasUyanik Please extract the handler function as I have done in my answer above.  This will allow you to place a proper breakpoint in the code.

Comment: To make a valid test using a string literal matching what he says is returning from the server, you must write it as `var goodData = "{\\\"data\\\":[], \\\"SkipToken\\\":\\\"\\\", \\\"top\\\":\\\"\\\"}"`.

Answer (score 5):

You say the server is returning the JSON (omitting the enclosing quotes):

```
{\"data\":[], \"SkipToken\":\"\", \"top\":\"\"}
```

This is invalid JSON. The quote marks in JSON surrounding strings and property names should **not** be preceded by a backslash. The backslash in JSON is strictly for inserting double quote marks **inside** a string. (It can also be used to escape other characters inside strings, but that is not relevant here.)

Correct JSON would be:

```
{"data":[], "SkipToken":"", "top":""}
```

If your server returned this, it would parse correctly.

The confusion here, and the reports by other posters that it seems like your string should work, lies in the fact that in a simple-minded test, where I type this string into the console:

```
var x = "{\"data\":[], \"SkipToken\":\"\", \"top\":\"\"}";
```

the **JavaScript string literal escaping mechanism**, which is entirely distinct from the use of escapes in JSON, results in a string with the value

```
{"data":[], "SkipToken":"", "top":""}
```

which of course JSON.parse can handle just fine. But Javascript string escaping applies to string literals in source code, not to things coming down from the server.

To fix the server's incorrectly-escaped JSON, you have two possibilities. One is to tell the server guys they don't need to (and must not) put backslashes before quote marks (except for quote marks **inside** strings). Then everything will work.

The other approach is to undo the escaping yourself before handing it off to `JSON.parse`. A first cut at this would be a simple regexp such as

```
data.replace(/\\"/g, '"')
```

as in

```
var dataList = JSON.parse(data.replace(/\\"/g, '"')
```

It might need additional tweaking depending on how the server guys are escaping quotes inside strings; are they sending `\"\\"\"`, or possibly `\"\\\"\"`?

I cannot explain why this code that was working suddenly stopped working. My best guess is a change on the server side that started escaping the double quotes.

Comment: Nice answer, @user663031.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean that your JSON is like this?

```
"{\"data\":[], \"SkipToken\":\"\", \"top\":\"\"}"
```

Then `data` in your callback would be like this:

```
'"{\"data\":[], \"SkipToken\":\"\", \"top\":\"\"}"'
```

Because `data` is the fetched text content string.

You don't have to add extra quotes in your JSON:

```
{"data":[], "SkipToken":"", "top":""}
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the JSON he pasted in the OP.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Actually, there is. `JSON.parse` will immediately choke on the backslash following the initial curly bracket. The only thing that can follow an opening curly bracket in JSON is the double quotation mark starting a property name. So, actually this answer is correct, although it could be a bit clearer, instead of "You don't have to add", it could be "The server must not add".

Comment: It didn't choke in a JS Fiddle.