# JSON.parse with all double quotes

Tags: javascript, json

I am facing one issue with below code snippet

My scenario is:

```js
var lit = "{"foo":"test \\"1\\"","bar":"test 2"}";

console.log(lit);

var thaw2 = JSON.parse(lit);
console.log(thaw2);
```

Due to the double quotes in lit object, I am getting an error "unexpected identifier".
I cannot chnage it to single quotes here, is there any solution to convert that string to json object with all double quotes?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you have invalid string literals to begin with? I'd focus on fixing that as currently you have source code that plain doesn't work - trying to "fix" the broken code is going to be involved and quite error prone.

Comment: Did you check this ?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30114429/error-parsing-json-with-escaped-quotes

Comment: Can you use this instead '{"foo": "test \\"1\\"", "bar": "test 2"}'

Comment: When you say you can't change to single quotes, do you mean you can't change the outside quotes at all or you just can't use single quotes?

Answer (score 1):

Escape the internal double quotes.

```js
var lit = "{\"foo\":\"test \\\"1\\\"\",\"bar\":\"test 2\"}";

console.log(lit);

var thaw2 = JSON.parse(lit);
console.log(thaw2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use single quotations instead of double quotations for outer most boundary.

```
var lit = '{"foo":"test \\"1\\"","bar":"test 2"}';

console.log(lit);

var thaw2 = JSON.parse(lit);
console.log(thaw2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Cause for your issue: When double quotes are used to define a string and used as part of the string, it considers as closing quotes.

To fix this:
Option 1: Use single quotes to start and end the string.

```
var lit = '{"foo":"test \\"1\\"","bar":"test 2"}';
```

This would not work in case u want to use single quotes inside ur string.
In that case use option 2.

Option 2: Escaping.
use \' or \" to escape the character

```
Eg: var lit = '{\'foo\':"test \\"1\\"","bar":"test 2"}'; (Escaping single quote)
var lit = "{\"foo\":\"test \\\"1\\\"\",\"bar\":\"test 2\"}"; (escaping double quote)
```